# EMR cluster monitoring configuration: Ganglia + InfluxDb

Tags: emr, amazon-emr, influxdb, terraform, ganglia

i have an EMR cluster. It is set up by terraform script

```
resource "aws_emr_cluster" "emr-test" {
   name = "emr-test"
   applications = [..., "Ganglia", ...]
   ...
}
```

I would like to integrate ganglia with influxDb+Grafana. Found an example of cofiguration: [example](https://sakamotomsh.wordpress.com/2014/06/03/poc-interactive-dashboard-w-gangliainfluxdbgrafana/).

That requires to update gmetad.conf file on master node. Is that possible to do that with terraform script? emr step?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [bootstrap_action](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/emr_cluster.html#bootstrap_action) attribute to list actions that should run before Hadoop is started on the cluster nodes. You can also apply filters to only run those actions on the master node:

```
resource "aws_emr_cluster" "emr-test" {

  ...

  bootstrap_action {
    path = "s3://your-bucket/update-gmetad.sh"
    name = "update-gmetad-on-master-node"
    args = ["instance.isMaster=true"]
  }

}
```